# Why all the data is Nan when I load NDVI image by rasterio or gdal

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff, rasterio

I calculated NDVI value and saved single band images following this page; https://developers.planet.com/docs/planetschool/calculate-an-ndvi-in-python/. After that I wanted to load those images on python by rasterio or gdal, loading images were succeeded, but unfortunately all the value was Nan. Why all the value is loaded as Nan? And how to fixed this situation?

I googled but could not find solutions. I need your helps, Plz...

Comment: fixed by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652695/gdal-readasarray-returns-just-nan-values-when-trying-to-read-envi-file

Answer (score 0):

You can use [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) as suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652695/gdal-readasarray-returns-just-nan-values-when-trying-to-read-envi-file):

```
mar = np.ma.masked_array(ar, np.isnan(ar))
print(mar.min(), np.median(mar), mar.mean(), mar.std(), mar.max())
```

This masked array allows calculations to be taken on the array without taking into account the invalid values.